# Understanding Escaping

Tags: shell, regular-expression, escape-characters

My source of question is [the answer here on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33423575/6639975), plus some extra things

**UPDATE**

**I understand the first command i.e `grep \\[[a-z\|1-9]*\\] file` but I don't understand the output of second command i.e `grep \[[a-z\|1-9]*\] file`.**

Now, I just want to understand how the output of second command is constructed especially why grep selected the whole third and fourth line completely, but selected the second and third line only up to the first `]`

[image]

Comment: You might usefully use the command `set -x` to get the shell to show you the command before it is executed. You will then see the effect of your escapes when not inside single quotes.

Comment: You also should consider that two different rules of escaping are in effect: The `bash` rules, which pass the argument to `grep`, and the rules `grep` uses for escaping. Replace `grep` with `echo` (or use `set -x`) to see the effect of the `bash` rules. Read `man grep` for the `grep` rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets walk slowly.
If there is a file with this content (in just one line to make it easier to show):

```
$ cat infile
list[1]; i[ab1]; var[1] [1]var  [1]var[2]
```

## a

A simple `grep --color a` will show in red all the a's.
(As this site does allow the control of colors : Assume that bold is red):

```
$ grep --color a infile
```

`list[1]; i[`**a**`b1]; v`**a**`r[1] [1]v`**a**`r  [1]v`**a**`r[2]`

Exactly the same happens if the a is un-quoted (as above) or if it is quoted:

```
$ grep --color \a infile
```

`list[1]; i[`**a**`b1]; v`**a**`r[1] [1]v`**a**`r  [1]v`**a**`r[2]`

```
$ grep --color "a" infile
```

`list[1]; i[`**a**`b1]; v`**a**`r[1] [1]v`**a**`r  [1]v`**a**`r[2]`

```
$ grep --color 'a' infile
```

`list[1]; i[`**a**`b1]; v`**a**`r[1] [1]v`**a**`r  [1]v`**a**`r[2]`

Why? Because the a's are **both**:

1. Not special to the shell.
2. The shell remove the quotes and grep receive the same `a` as first argument. Either a backslash quote, a double quote, or a single quote.

## ]

If we want to select the braces `]` (lets start with the closing brace):

```
$ grep --color ] infile
```

`list[1`**]**`; i[ab1`**]**`; var[1`**]**`[1`**]**`var  [1`**]**`var[2`**]**

The same will happen if the `]` were quoted (any quote).
In this case the `]` is special to the shell but not in this case where there is no matching opening brace.

For a closing brace, things get one step more complex. All of this raise an error:

```
grep --color  [  infile
grep --color '[' infile
grep --color "[" infile
```

Why? Because what grep receive in **all** cases is a single `[`.
You can undestand what the shell does with this simple echo:

```
 $ echo \[ "[" '['
 [ [ [
```

The shell remove one level of quoting and all values look the same.

## [

But what grep wants to receive to undestand that we are actually searching for the character `[` is a backslash quoted square brace (`\[`). That will happen with all of this:

```
$ echo \\[ "\[" '\['
\[ \[ \[
```

And grep will work with any of those:

```
$ grep --color \\[ infile
```

`list`**[**`1]; i`**[**`ab1]; var`**[**`1]`**[**`1]var`**[**`1]var`**[**`2]`

## [[]

Using `[[]` (a character list with only one character) will get to the same result (as long as it is quoted).

```
$ grep --color '[[]' infile
```

`list`**[**`1]; i`**[**`ab1]; var`**[**`1]`**[**`1]var`**[**`1]var`**[**`2]`

Grep needs to receive exactly `[[]` for this to work. It may seem that no quotes are really needed:

```
$ echo \[\[\] "[[]" '[[]' [[]
[[] [[] [[] [[]
```

But if you create a file named `[`, that idea will break:

```
$ touch \[
$ echo \[\[\] "[[]" '[[]' [[]
[[] [[] [[] [
```

that is because the `[` is special to the shell. To the shell, it starts a filename globbing pattern. If a file (or many) match the pattern, the list of files is substituted.

So, this will work correctly:

```
$  grep --color '[[]' infile
```

`list`**[**`1]; i`**[**`ab1]; var`**[**`1]`**[**`1]var`**[**`1]var`**[**`2]`

And this: `grep --color '[]]' infile` will match the closing brace.

## [][]

To match both the opening square brace **and** the closing square brace, you need an specific sequence of characters (quoted, of course).

If you try this:

```
$  grep --color '[[]]' infile
```

There will be no match, none at all. You need this to get it working correctly:

```
$ grep --color '[][]' infile
```

`list`**[**`1`**]**`; i`**[**`ab1`**]**`; var`**[**`1`**]****[**`1`**]**`var`**[**`1`**]**`var`**[**`2`**]**

In that specific order, the closing brace must be the first character inside the character range. The opening brace must be the last character in the character list.

## []a-z0-9[]

Then, you can add other characters (only not the `;`):

```
$ grep --color '[]a-z0-9[]' infile
```

**list[1]**`;`**i[ab1]**`;`**var[1]****[1]var****[1]var[2]**

And then, you can add the missing `|` in the range and do the match that is the link you posted. The regex in that link is not the same as here, and works in a very differnt way. It starts by matching one `[`, some other characters and end with a closing `]`. Something similar to (the greedy nature of the `*` takes the whole line):

```
$  grep --color '\[.*\]' infile
```

`list`**[1]; i[ab1]; var[1] [1]var  [1]var[2]**

Or also similar to this:

```
$ grep --color '[[][a-c0-9]*[]]' infile
```

`list`**[1]**`; i`**[ab1]**`; var`**[1]****[1]**`var`**[1]**`var`**[2]**`

Comment: Oh boy, this was intense to understand, but you made it so much clearer. Thank you sir.. I see what's happening in my code now. Thanks again.. You put so much time into this answer explaining very useful stuff..

Answer (score 2):

There are too many variables and undeclared assumptions here to answer your question exhaustively.

The main trap here is that the shell (i.e. most Bourne-compatible shells - not actually sure about zsh or csh and derivatives) by defaut will pass through a glob unexpanded *if it doesn't match anything.* So an expression like `\\[[a-z0-9]*\\]` is first attempted as a wildcard. **If** there are no matching files (like `\fno[rd\]` where the nonalphabetics are all literal) the wildcard is passed on to `grep` verbatim.

(Let's examine that again. That's a double backslash, i.e. a quoted literal backslash followed by two opening square brackets. The first creates a character class, the first character of which is the second, literal `[`. The result of parsing this as a regular expression is different, but similarly convoluted.)

The only sane solution to this is to properly quote anything which does not need to undergo whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion by the shell. My recommendation is to use single quotes around all your regular expressions. You will then be able to form a reasonable expectation for what will match and how, without *two* expert interpretations (one shell, one regex) of your patterns.

If you are trying to match `var[1]` entirely, a regex like `[a-z]*\[[0-9]*\]` does something like that. If you want the square brackets to be part of the character class, try `[][a-z0-9]*` where the first `]` and the second `[` are literal members of the character class. And remember the single quotes around these if you pass them to `grep` in the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tripleee , I have updated my question to be as precise as possible after last 4 hours research. Have a last look please. Thank you so much for the help...

Comment: I don't see how to make this any clearer. Your regex specifies a big ole character class which ends just before the Kleene star and then requires a literal `]` at the end of the match.

Comment: I understood, thank you so much for your valuable time. :)